# Stripe: Cannot charge a customer that has no active card

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a customer and charge that customer using Rails and Stripe. The customer is getting created in Stripe, but I keep getting the error `Cannot charge a customer that has no active card` when trying to do the charge.

I am following a stripe tutorial as a Rails beginner, so I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Rails code:**

```
def process_payment
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email,
                                       card: card_token

    Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id,
                          amount: level.price*100,
                          description: level.name,
                          card: card_token,
                          currency: 'usd'

  end

  def create
    @registration = Registration.new registration_params.merge(email: stripe_params["stripeEmail"],
                                                               card_token: stripe_params["stripeToken"])
    raise "Please, check registration errors" unless @registration.valid?
    @registration.process_payment
    @registration.save
    redirect_to @registration, notice: 'Registration was successfully created.'
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating the charge without the card_token. You shouldn't need to specify the card a second time, since the card is attached to the customer, which you're specifying though the `customer` parameter.

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email,
                                   source: card_token

Stripe::Charge.create customer: customer.id,
                      amount: level.price*100,
                      description: level.name,
                      currency: 'usd'
```

Also, pass the `card_token` through the `source` param, rather than the deprecated `card` param. Here is a blog post that talks about this change: https://stripe.com/blog/unifying-payment-types-in-the-api

More info: https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_customer
and: https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

Comment: thanks for the help! although, removing the card token from the charge call didn't help. I've attached a screenshot of the test data error. See above.

Comment: I think Stripe may have changed the Customer API so that `card` is now `source` (see https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_customer). Try that and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't think im getting values to my model, how can i test that? `customer = Stripe::Customer.create email: email,
                                       card: card_token`

Comment: Try passing card_token through the `source` parameter to the customer object, rather than `card`. Updated the answer to show this.

Comment: Are you using test credentials?

Comment: @TreyCopeland, did you ever solve the problem? If you did, how so?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are following a Udemy course. You'll have a JavaScript file for token creation that actually is not executing at the time of the signup click, so no token is being generated.

Include that JavaScript file in layout/application file and then make sure your jQuery is working perfectly, otherwise rewrite that code totally into vanilla JavaScript instead of using the jQuery method.

The rest of the code is working perfect on the Ruby side.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is charge a customer once you have created a payment method for her. However, you cannot use the `Charge` endpoint to do that if you have not set any subscriptions because this method is made for recurring payments linked to subscriptions.

In order to be able to charge your client, set a subscription. This will activate the card. You'll then be able to debit the card.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can create a checkout session and add the card to the customer. This will trigger a checkout path to the Stripe API, and you can take the card token from there by passing the customer. After you can create charge.

```
session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create(
          customer: customer,
          payment_method_types: ['card'],
          line_items: [{
              name: product.product_name,
              amount: product.price.to_i,
              currency: 'usd',
              quantity: 1
          }],
          mode: 'payment',
          success_url: product_url(product),
          cancel_url:  product_url(product)
          )
          redirect_to session.url
```

Hope this can help anyone with this issue.

Answer (score -4):

You're trying to access the parameters, so you must use the `params` keyword.

Instead of `card_token`, use `params["card_token"]`